# Storing an array of ranges of timestamps into postgresql using PlaySlick and slick-pg

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to store a List of Ranges of Timestamps into the "available" column of a PostgreSQL table. I'm using [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) to help out. For the table data I have:

```
create table users (
    id text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    action text NOT NULL,
    scheduled timestamptz,
    available tstzrange[]
);
```

In my DAO I have:

```
private class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

    def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def action = column[String]("action")
    def timestamp = column[Option[Timestamp]]("scheduled")
    def available = column[Option[List[com.github.tminglei.slickpg.Range[Timestamp]]]]("available")

    def * = (id, action, timestamp, available) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
}
```

And an associated case class for the table:

```
case class User(id: String, action: String, timestamp: Option[Timestamp] = None, available:Option[List[com.github.tminglei.slickpg.Range[Timestamp]]] = None)
```

I know I'm missing an implicit, something similar to the implicits in this [example file](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/PgArraySupportSuite.scala). However I'm still new to Scala and stuck on exactly how to define it.

Answer (score 0):

In the class you are doing some DAO accesses, inject `DatabaseConfigProvider` like this:

```
class Class @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
```

and make it `extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[MyPostgresDriver]`.

You have to import: (database is the name of the package where is the MyPostgresDriver file)

```
import database.MyPostgresDriver.api._
import database.MyPostgresDriver
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
```

Here is the MyPostgresDriver file:

```
package database

import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._

trait MyPostgresDriver extends ExPostgresDriver
    with PgArraySupport
    with PgDate2Support
    with PgPlayJsonSupport
    with PgNetSupport
    with PgLTreeSupport
    with PgRangeSupport
    with PgHStoreSupport
    with PgSearchSupport
    with PgPostGISSupport {

  override val pgjson = "jsonb"
  override lazy val Implicit = new ImplicitsPlus {}
  override val simple = new SimpleQLPlus {}

  trait ImplicitsPlus extends Implicits
  with ArrayImplicits
  with DateTimeImplicits
  with RangeImplicits
  with HStoreImplicits
  with JsonImplicits
  with SearchImplicits
  with PostGISImplicits

  trait SimpleQLPlus extends SimpleQL
  with ImplicitsPlus
  with SearchAssistants
  with PostGISAssistants

  override val api = new API with ArrayImplicits
    with DateTimeImplicits
    with PlayJsonImplicits
    with NetImplicits
    with LTreeImplicits
    with RangeImplicits
    with HStoreImplicits
    with SearchImplicits
    with PostGISImplicits
    with SearchAssistants {}
}

object MyPostgresDriver extends MyPostgresDriver
```

(Choose only the needed implicits).